# Show that if f'' is positive on an interval [a,b], then f' has at most one zero in [a,b]

Tags: calculus

Show that: $f''>0$ on [a,b], then $f'$ has at most one zero in [a,b].

How do I prove this? $f''>0$ implies that it is a concave up function right?

Comment: You don’t care about $f$ itself: you care about $f'$. If $f''>0$ , what property does $f'$ have?

Comment: But what if $f'$ is not differentiable or even not continuous? You might want to check Darboux's intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Put $g(x)=f'(x)$ and then rephrase the question in term of $g$.

Answer (score 2):

If $f''>0$, then this means that $f'$ is strictly increasing.

Suppose that $f'(x_0)=0$, for a particular $x_0$. Then $x<x_0\implies f'(x)<f(x_0)=0$, and $x>x_0\implies f'(x)>f(x_0)=0$, because $f'$ is strictly increasing. Therefore, if $f$ has one root, it is nonzero for all remaining values of $x$, *i.e.* $f'$ has at most one root.

Comment: How do I prove the theorem using lagrange mean value theorem?

Comment: Let $x,y$ be distinct points in $[a,b]$. By the Mean Value Theorem applied to $f'$ there is a $\xi$ in between $x$ and $y$ for which $f(x)-f(y)=f'(\xi)(x-y)$. This is nonzero because $f'(\xi)>0$ and $x\neq y$. This means $f$ doesn't take the same value twice, so it has at most one zero.

Comment: what is the guarantee that it has a zero?

Comment: There is no guarantee, e.g. $f(x)=x^2+1$.